# How do I recreate this logo pattern? Any suggestions?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, vector, logo

I am trying to recreate the pattern below, anyone know how this can be re-created? This pattern is from the Princess House logo. It is made of up about 6 small circles but how do I use illustrator to create this?

[image]

Comment: This tutorial could be helpful: https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-evenly-distribute-objects-along-a-path-in-adobe-illustrator--vector-5175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a screenshot of the picture then pasted it in Illustrator and ensured it is centered on the artboard. Then drew an ellipse and rotated it accordingly (I used the drawing but if I'd had more time, I'd calculate the required angle of rotation to be more precise).

[image]

Then I drew the top circles over the existing design, and using the center point, duplicated them around the pivoting point and erased the screenshot and ellipses.

[image]
[image]

If you need more precisions on any of these steps, leave a comment and I will update my answer.